# How do I downgrade MinGW GCC to 4.8,4?

Tags: windows-10, c++, gcc, mingw, downgrade

I'm starting a C++ course in college, and they asked for all assignments to be compilable on GCC 4.8.4.

I decided to go with MinGW on Windows 10 via Eclipse, but on the "Versions" tab of any given entry in the MinGW Installation Manager, all I see is "FIXME:data sheet unavailable; a compiler for this data category has yet to be implemented."

I've tried to uninstall the GCC on my command-line Ubuntu and install the relevant version, but it stays on the current (7.2) version...

Any ideas? Suggestions? G++? Something?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there any reason to suspect that a College C++ (beginner? standard c++!) course would contain (i.e REQUIRE) anything that would not compile on an older gcc?  FWIW: I would answer "no" to that.

Comment: I'm not sure why, honestly -- all I know is that that is the version their automated checker uses, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MinGW-W64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) project has older versions of GCC for Windows available via their [Sourceforge downloads page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/). You'll probably want the `Toolchains targeting  Win32` or `Toolchains targeting Win64` folders.

Note that there are quite a number of potential available builds but just as a recommendation, you may want to look at the `Personal\mingw-builds` subfolder(s). Regarding what version to download (threads-win32/threads-posix, sjlj/dwarf), have a look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17242516/3395469) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15670169/3395469) if you need to begin to get a handle on which version to choose.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much!!

Comment: Question: the SLJL/SEH question mentions SEH isn't supported by GCC, but it still exists in the repository -- is it just the first one, DWARF?
(Sorry for double-comment, accidental Enter)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. That answer is a bit outdated. The answer below it mentions that SEH was slated to be added in GCC 4.8.x (it was). SEH versions are available under the 64-bit builds.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, just tried the 32-bit build and it does indeed miss SEH.
Last question (hopefully) -- should there be a 'bin' folder? I'm not sure how to use GCC without it....

Comment: Yes, there should be a `bin` folder that holds all the necessary executables.

Comment: Oh, oops, apparently it didn't extract everything the first time -- works perfectly, thank you so, so much =D

Comment: Not a problem. Have fun. =)